# Python doesn't display cp1254 characters in Cmd

Tags: python, cmd, character, display

When I double click a python module, it opens in Cmd (but it writes python.exe) and it doesn't show strings as cp1254 (gibberish).

*Here is my module in Python Shell*:
[image: module]

When I open the module in IDLE and run it, it opens in Python Shell and it works great.

*Here is my module in Cmd*:
[image: module python]

So, how can I display strings as cp1254 characters in cmd?

Comment: What's your default code page in `cmd` (type `chcp` into `cmd` to find out)?

Comment: Active code page: 857
It's Turkish code page but the cmd doesn't allow Turkish characters when Python is running.